# I fail to understand why this code does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

This should change the shown image (the 2 images are on top of each other). I'm operating with the active class which has an opacity of 100 and should be over the not active one (z-index). The not active image has an opacity of 0. When the image is clicked the other one should get the 100 opacity and the higher z-index. (the animations are not important).

- First weird thing: at the fresh page, the down-arrow is showing even though it does not have the active class
- Second weird thing: when I click on the image, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_container">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h1>Menü megnyitása</h1>
</td>
<td>
<img src="arrow_up.gif" alt="arrow" class="arrow_up active_img"/> 
<img src="arrow_down.gif" alt="arrow" class="arrow_down"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS of the normal and active image:

```
#menu_container table tr td img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    opacity:0%;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.active_img {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:100;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    }
```

And finally the script itself:

```
var menu = function() {
    $('.arrow_up').click(function() {
        $('#header').animate({top: '10%'}, 300);
        $('#menu_container').animate({top: '15%'},300);

        var active = $('.active_img');

        active.removeClass('active_img');
        active.next().addClass('active_img');

        $('#menu_list').show();
    });
    $('.arrow_down').click(function() {
        $('#header').animate({top: '50%'}, 300);
        $('#menu_container').animate({top: '55%'},300);

        var active = $('.active_img');

        active.removeClass('active_img');
        active.prev().addClass('active_img');

        $('#menu_list').hide();
    });
};
$(document).ready(menu);
```

Comment: Opacity goes from 0 to 1, not using percent sign.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the code.

1. The `opacity` is measured from `0` to `1`, without percentages.
2. The `opacity` at `.active_img` doesn't overrule the default `opacity`, because there are more selectors at the first rule, which makes it more important.
3. The `td` in the `#menu_container` isn't positioned, which makes the images positioned absolute but relative to the window instead of the `td`.
4. The `#menu_container` isn't positioned, which makes it stay still when you animate `top`.

```js
var menu = function() {
    $('.arrow_up').click(function() {
        $('#header').animate({top: '10%'}, 300);
        $('#menu_container').animate({top: '15%'},300);

        var active = $('.active_img');

        active.removeClass('active_img');
        active.next().addClass('active_img');

        $('#menu_list').show();
    });
    $('.arrow_down').click(function() {
        $('#header').animate({top: '50%'}, 300);
        $('#menu_container').animate({top: '55%'},300);

        var active = $('.active_img');

        active.removeClass('active_img');
        active.prev().addClass('active_img');

        $('#menu_list').hide();
    });
};
$(document).ready(menu);
```

```css
#menu_container {
  position:absolute;
}

#menu_container table tr td {
  position:relative;
}

#menu_container table tr td img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  opacity:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index:1;
}

#menu_container table tr td .active_img {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu_container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
 <h1>Menü megnyitása</h1>
      </td>
      <td>
 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_up active_img"/> 
 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow_down"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The initial act of the header going down is caused by the fact that the initial `top` value isn't defined. But I don't know if that's supposed to happen, so I'll leave it that way.

This doesn't solve any of the design problems, but that isn't my task.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done much easier.

```
<div id="toggler">
<img src="image1.jpeg"/>
<img src="image2.jpeg" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<script>
$("#toggler").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Noted, I will be using something like this when I will be facing a similar problem. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To make your code work all you have to do is just remove the z-index:1 in your #menu_container table tr td img style.

```
#menu_container table tr td img {
width:50px;
height:50px;
opacity:0%;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: Thanks,works after removing z-index from all the img-s. but may I ask what is the reasoning behind this?